# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f913820)

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am trying to add a collectionView programatically to a subview.But when I return number of items as 1 ,collection is loading somany number of cells.Here I am using SharkORM in my project,Will it effects collectionView?.My actual requirement is I will be having files ,The collection of images need to store in relevant file.but this collection view is not loading required number of cells.Can anyone help to solve this.

```
func createCollection(){

        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 82, height: 82)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.customView.frame.size.width-20, height: self.customView.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReviewCollectionCellPage", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ReviewCollectionCellPage")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        customView.addSubview(collectionView)

    }






extension ReviewViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(finalImages.count)
        return finalImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       // print(finalImages)
        let cell : ReviewCollectionCellPage = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewCollectionCellPage", for: indexPath) as! ReviewCollectionCellPage
            cell.finalImage.image = UIImage(named: "images.png")
        collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        }
}
```

Comment: Remove the reloadData() from "func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs into an infinite loop.

In `cellForRow` calling `reloadData` calls `cellForRow` which calls `reloadData` which calls `cellForRow` which calls `reloadData` which calls `cellForRow` which calls `reloadData` which calls `cellForRow` which calls `reloadData` which calls `cellForRow` which calls `reloadData` which calls `cellForRow`... which  with an overflow exception

Delete `collectionView.reloadData()` in `cellForRow` and reload the data right after populating the data source array.